# Display set of Views rows with different view modes

Tags: views, 8, entities

I have a Drupal 8 View with a set of rows, which are each rendered as a compact list teaser. Additionally I need to display those rows inside the same view in a another view mode (e.g. "grid teaser" with an extra image). As a result the visitor should be able to switch between the different view modes by toggling the display.

The template `views-view.html.twig` should contain this:

```
<!-- [...] -->
<!-- Display rows as list teaser -->
<div class="view-list row">
  {{ rows }}
</div>
<!-- Display rows as grid teaser -->
<div class="view-grid row">
  {{ rows_grid }}
</div>
<!-- [...] -->
```

I don't really know how to render those additional rows. I thought about using the hook `template_preprocess_views_view`:

```
function template_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {

  // collect node ids
  $nids_rows = array();
  foreach ($variables['view']->result as $row){
    $nids_rows[] = $row->nid;
  }

  // load nodes
  $nodes_rows = Node::loadMultiple($nids_rows);

  if(!empty($nodes_rows)){
    // get views of nodes as grid
    $variables['rows_grid'][] = node_view_multiple($nodes_rows, 'grid');
  }
}
```

But the resulting render array is not in the same form like `$variables['rows']` and I'm not able to loop through those `rows_grid` to wrap them with specific html (like in `views-view-unformatted.html.twig`).

Is there a function like `view_load_rows($nids, $view_mode)`? Or is there a way to alter the render array with some additional keys like '#theme' to get a real `rows` render array?

Maybe there is even an much simpler way to accomplish this. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another view display and put it below the main view output using block or view attachment.

Comment: It works, although I'm still interested in rendering rows programmatically.

Comment: @PhilippMichael, did you figure out a programmatic solution? I'm looking for a similar solution at the moment.

Comment: @Randell, no I have not found a programmatic solution but I think setting up a view attachment is best practice here. I've seen this in various drupal 8 sites.

Comment: I actually went with the same solution (re: attachment).

Comment: @ya.teck can you share an example for multiple view displays in single view ?